# Show/Hide Fieldset with JQuery Mobile Sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm going to have about 10 fieldsets, and I want each to show depending on the value of the Number of Buildings slider.

How do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvVmT/1061/

HTML:

```
 <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="col-half">
                                <h4>Number of Buildings</h4>
                                <input type="range" name="NoBslider" id="NoBslider" data-popup-enabled="true" value="0" min="0" max="10">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-half">
                                <h4>Number of Bulk Meters</h4>
                                <input type="range" name="points" id="points" data-popup-enabled="true" value="0" min="0" max="100">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset data-role="collapsible" class="building">
                            <legend>Building 1</legend>
                            <label for="maila">Building Street</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="col-half">
                                    <div class="input-group-icon">
                                        <div class="col-third">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Street Number" name="maila" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-third">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street Name" name="maila" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-third">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street Type" name="maila" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="col-third">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">

                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Residential Units" name="comments" />
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-third">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">

                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Commercial Units" name="comments" />
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-third">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Commons" name="comments" />
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset data-role="collapsible" class="building">
                            <legend>Building 2</legend>
                            <label for="maila">Building Street</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="col-half">
                                    <div class="input-group-icon">
                                        <div class="col-third">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Street Number" name="maila" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-third">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street Name" name="maila" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-third">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street Type" name="maila" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="col-third">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">

                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Residential Units" name="comments" />
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-third">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">

                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Commercial Units" name="comments" />
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-third">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Commons" name="comments" />
                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
```

JQuery:

```
    hidebuildings($("#NoBslider"));
    $("#NoBslider").on("change", function () {
        hidebuildings($(this));
    });
    function hidebuildings(slider) {
        var theVal = slider.val();
                        if (theVal = 2){
            $('.building').show();
            $('.building1').show();

        }

        });
```

Wanted to just test and see if I could get the fieldsets to show if I had the slider on value 2. It's not working of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon, such a filter is not difficult to implement, but you are right to ask because there could be many subtle issues by putting all the things together.

First of all, if you need a predefined list of elements of same type, please be sure you have in your markup unique identifiers - for labels, elements, and so on, which you need - otherwise nothing won't work.

I suggest you, to put the collapsibles inside a collapsibleset, you you will end up with a nice JQM style for the whole group. Then the filter is done by adding the class `.ui-screen-hidden` to the unwanted collapsibleset children. After that, simply invoke `$("selector").collapsibleset("refresh");`

Working example:

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-one", function() {
  $("#buildings .ui-collapsible").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
  });
  $("#NoBslider").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#buildings .ui-collapsible").each(function(index) {
      $(this).toggleClass("ui-screen-hidden", index >= val);
    });
    $("#buildings").collapsibleset("refresh");
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-slider input {
    display: none !important;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-track {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h4>Please choose...</h4>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            Nr. of Buildings
          </div>
          <input type="range" name="NoBslider" id="NoBslider" data-popup-enabled="true" value="0" min="0" max="10">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            Nr. of Bulk Meters
          </div>
          <input type="range" name="points" id="points" data-popup-enabled="true" value="0" min="0" max="100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="buildings">
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 1</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 2</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 3</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 4</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 5</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 6</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 7</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 8</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 9</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
          <legend>Building 10</legend>
          <fieldset><input type="text" placeholder="Street Name"></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, note also the onchange event handler for the slider shall be attached to the desired element when JQM raises the `onpagecreate` event.